# What is the proper way to chain Tasks when returning a Task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am so so with using Tasks in C# but I get confused when I try to return a Task from a method and that method will do multiple tasks within itself. So do I have my method spin up a new Task and then do everything sequentially inside of there? It's hard to wrap my head around doing it all with  .ContinueWith()

Example:

```
public Task<string> GetSomeData(CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var initialData = GetSomeInteger(token).Result;

        return GetSomeString(initialData, token).Result;
    });
}

public Task<int> GetSomeInteger(CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return 4;
    }, token);
}

public Task<string> GetSomeString(int value, CancellationToken token)
{
    return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }, token);
}
```

I am unsure how else to write this method to make it use Tasks correctly. I guess I just feel like there should be a .ContinueWith in there or something.

Possible fix??

```
public Task<string> GetSomeData(CancellationToken token)
{
    return GetSomeInteger(token).ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
    {
        return GetSomeString(prevTask.Result, token);
    }, token).Unwrap();
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to recommend something without having the **context**. Could you please provide some concrete details about the methods which return `Task`s?

Comment: Can you show the actual declaration of `SomeOtherMethodWhichReturnsTask` and `MethodWhichAlsoReturnsTask`?  What you have now is kind of crazy, as it's a method which returns `Task<Task<string>>`, which I suspect is wrong...

Comment: @Serge I guess if this is the best way to write a method that returns a Task when that method needs to call other methods which also returns a task. I wonder if I need to change those calls to the other methods with .ContinueWith

Comment: @ReedCopsey sure I just wrote that and made up stuff. Didn't think it was needed to know what those other methods were or did.

Comment: @Travyguy9 With the proper method signatures, it might be possible (it usually is) to do this without spinning up a task.  But it's impossible to tell without seeing the actual methods in play...

Comment: @ReedCopsey I don't think so. I am pretty sure the UnWrap I am using is in .NET 4.0  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917.aspx

Comment: @Travyguy9 Oh, yeah - I forgot that got added in.  That would work.  It's basically doing what my second example does, btw

Comment: BTW, you can usually just write `Task.Factory.StartNew(lambda)`, you don't need the generic parameter there.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In general, it's often best to try to avoid spinning up new tasks if you are already working with task-based methods.  Chaining tasks instead of blocking explicitly will reduce the overhead of the system, as it won't keep a ThreadPool thread tied up waiting.

That being said, it's often simpler to just block as you're doing.

Note that C# 5 makes this far simpler, providing an API that gives you the best of both:

```
public async Task<string> GetSomeData(CancellationToken token)
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    var initialData = await SomeOtherMethodWhichReturnsTask(token);

    string result = await initialData.MethodWhichAlsoReturnsTask(token);

    return result;
};
```

---

Edit after update:

Given the new code, there isn't an easy way to chain this directly with `ContinueWith`.  There are a couple of options.  You can use [Unwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917.aspx) to convert the `Task<Task<string>>` you'd create, ie:

```
public Task<string> GetSomeData(CancellationToken token)
{
    Task<Task<string>> task = GetSomeInteger(token)
                               .ContinueWith(t => 
                               {
                                   return GetSomeString(t.Result, token);
                               }, token);
    return task.Unwrap();
}
```

Alternatively, you can handle the unwrapping yourself elegantly with [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx):

```
public Task<string> GetSomeData(CancellationToken token)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    Task<int> task1 = GetSomeInteger(token);
    Task<Task<string>> task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t => GetSomeString(t.Result, token));
    task2.ContinueWith(t => tcs.SetResult(t.Result.Result));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This allows the entire process to work without creating a new Task (which ties up a threadpool thread), and without ever blocking.

Note that you would probably want to add continuations on cancellation, and use [tcs.SetCancelled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449188.aspx) when a cancellation was requested, as well.

Comment: How would I write it with chaining then? I have a thought but it just feels wrong

Comment: Why don't you just directly return `task2`? You don't need the `TaskCompletionSource` there.

Comment: @svick task2 is `Task<Task<string>>` since the second method returns `Task<string>` - I just edited to make it more clear.

Comment: `GetSomeData` may actually block a taskpool thread waiting for `GetSomeString` to complete, since at the time of `t.Result.Result`, the `t.Result` task (which is `GetSomeString`) would potentially still be ongoing. Instead, this will not block at all: `GetSomeInteger(token).ContinueWith(ot => GetSomeString(ot.Result, token).ContinueWith(it => tcs.SetResult(it.Result)));`

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks#continuations-that-return-task-types) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-unwrap-a-nested-task) are good explanation about [Unwrap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap?view=net-5.0) method

Answer (score 6):

Here is an extension method that I built to solve this. Works in .Net 4+

```
public static Task<TNewResult> ContinueWith<T, TNewResult>(this Task<T> task, Func<Task<T>, Task<TNewResult>> continuationFunction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TNewResult>();
    task.ContinueWith(t => 
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        }
        continuationFunction(t).ContinueWith(t2 => 
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested || t2.IsCanceled)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else if (t2.IsFaulted)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(t2.Exception);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(t2.Result);
            }
        });
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Would help if you can also post a Usage of this extension method with a simple example :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, everything will run sequentially within your main task.  This is because calling the Result property will block the current thread until the value has returned.

Comment: I understand that, but SHOULD it run sequentially in there when I call out .Result? Or should I chain it with .ContinueWith and once I have the final result, return that value (.Result)

Comment: You probably should be chaining these tasks together, but this really does depend on whether you use these tasks independently or with other tasks in some other different scenarios.  Result definitely should block - this is a no limitation and it should be taken advantage of by developers.  Using ContinueWith has a performance benefit as the scheduler will know what thread to execute it.